# Detect contact normals in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am using two versions of gazebo on two different PCs one with Hydro and gazebo 1.9 and the other PC is with Indigo and Gazebo 2.2. In both I uploaded the same empty_world.world. In addition I uploaded a block model, the same model that has contact with ground plane(lies on the ground plane)in both versions of gazebo. In gazebo 1.9 I can see in the topic ~/physics/contact the 1 contact that I should see (in steady state). However in gazebo 2.2 I see this contact in the beginning  (transition state, for a second) and then 0 contacts in steady state.

What could be the problem? Where is the problem? If its a bug, in what version of gazebo?

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191664/detect-contact-normals-in-gazebo/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found an answer. there is a parameter in gazebo: <allow_auto_disable> 0 </allow_auto_disable> the default value is 1 and it should be zero for my purposes

---

Originally posted by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) with karma: 302 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0